# Meaning in context of 'founding population'

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Bryan Sykes, an Oxford scientist, wrote a book called "The Seven Daughters of Eve" in which, using studies of mitochondrial DNA, he had claimed to be able to trace nearly all living Europeans back to a founding population of just seven women—the 'daughters of Eve' of the title—who lived during the Palaeolithic. To each of these women Sykes given a name—Ursula, Xenia, Jasmine and so on—and even a detailed personal history.

Can the paragraph above have the implication that the 'daughters of Eve' lived in the same generation? If so, why? Is the use of 'founding population' that create this implication? Would it be sufficient to remove 'founding' to avoid this implication?

Answer (score 1):

The use of the word [*population*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/population) certainly implies they were all alive at the same time:-

> 1. the total number of persons inhabiting a country, city, or any district or area.
> 2. the body of inhabitants of a place: The population of the city opposes the addition of fluorides to the drinking water.
> 3. the number or body of inhabitants of a particular race or class in a place: the native population; the working-class population.
> 4. Statistics.  ...
> 5. Ecology . 
>      a. the assemblage of a specific type of organism living in a given area. 
>      b. all the individuals of one species in a given area.
> 6. ...

as someone who is dead or not yet born can't be said to be living in or inhabiting a given area. But it doesn't imply they were all "of the same generation", as in having roughly similar ages or being sisters or cousins or something of that sort.

Comment: I would have thought a *founding population* implied that they were all bearing children at roughly the same time. Otherwise, either the descendants of the eldest were separated from the others (in which case there is a daughter who has a better claim to be 'part of the founding generation'), or they were not (in which case *founding* seems misused, since some founders owe their existence to others).  But it's a minor point, and owes as much to biology as to English.

Comment: Not necessarily. One member could be a venerable matriarch with umpteen grandchildren, and others younger with a couple of children each. The matriarch's grandchildren could also be said to be part of the founding population, but that would make the number of them larger.